# Iteration over list seems to be broken

Tags: vimscript

I entered these statement:

```
let list = [[[0,0],[0,0],0], [[0,0],[0,0],0]]
for [a,b,c] in list
    let c = 5
endfor
```

And then when I executed `echo list`, I get

```
[[[0,0],[0,0],0], [[0,0],[0,0],0]]
```

I.e. nothing changed at all. Why is this? This seems like an error to me.

Especially because

```
let list = [[[0,0],[0,0],0], [[0,0],[0,0],0]]
for [a,b,c] in list
    let b[0] = 5
endfor
```

Does what you would expect it does. What explains this seemingly erratic behavior?

Comment: `a` and `b` are lists, so they are passed by reference.  `c` is a number, so it's passed by value.  Changing `list` by changing `b` works by accident, not by design.  Relying on this behaviour is asking for segfaults later on.  At the very least, the reference counts can be wrong in more complicated expressions.  Make sure you understand the difference between lvalues and rvalues before even considering going there.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're deconstructing each list item into `[a, b, c]`.  `c` is a copy since it's not an object, which would be the case in a lot of other languages.

This is basically what your example does:

```
let list = [[[0,0],[0,0],0], [[0,0],[0,0],0]]
for item in list
  let c = item[2]
  let c = 5
endfor
```

This is what you want to do:

```
let list = [[[0,0],[0,0],0], [[0,0],[0,0],0]]
for item in list
  let item[2] = 5
endfor
```

Comment: So to actually write over the third item, you need: `let item[2] = 5`

Comment: @SatoKatsura are you referring to my answer? The example shows the mistake in hgiesel's reasoning. Not "magically" turning `c` into a reference.

Comment: Sorry, too much blood in my coffee system. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura No sweat. I clarified the answer with a solution.